# Issue in Joining, getting incorrect output

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want to calculate the total sales for each individual AudiEvent including events where there were no sales. Sales will be calculated as BasePrice*PriceMultiplier. So grouping will be based on the EventName and should get the total sales.

```
SELECT  AudiEvent.EventName, 
        AudiEvent.EventDate, 
        AudiEvent.StartTime,
        SUM(Cast(AuditoriumRows.PriceMultiplier*AudiEvent.BasePrice as DECIMAL(4,1))) as "Total Sales"
FROM    AudiEvent
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserver 
    ON AudiEvent.AuditoriumID=Reserver.AuditoriumID
INNER JOIN AuditoriumRows 
    ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=AuditoriumRows.AuditoriumID
INNER JOIN Auditorium 
    ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=Auditorium.AuditoriumID
GROUP BY AudiEvent.EventName;
```

OUTPUT-

```
EventName       EventDate  StartTime Total Sales
Big Bash        29/6/2014  20:00      24480
County Cricket  06/07/2014 11:00       0
IPL             05/05/2014 03:00       0
```

INPUT-

Auditorium

```
AudiID  AudiName 
Audi01  London Theatre 
Audi02  Brentwood Hall 
Audi03  County Hall
```

AudiEvent

```
EventID AudiID EventName       BasePrice
1    Audi01 Big Bash          300
2    Audi01 County Cricket    400
3    Audi01 Big Bash          300
4    Audi01 Big Bash          300
5    Audi01 County Cricket    300
6    Audi01 Big Bash          300
7    Audi01 Big Bash          310
8    Audi01 County Cricket    400
9    Audi01 County Cricket    400
10   Audi01 County Cricket    400
11   Audi02 County Cricket    500
12   Audi02 County Cricket    520
13   Audi02 County Cricket    500
14   Audi02 County Cricket    500
15   Audi02 County Cricket    500
16   Audi03 IPL               1000
17   Audi03 IPL               1000
18   Audi03 IPL               1000
19   Audi03 Big Bash          350
20   Audi03 Big Bash          350
```

AuditoriumRows

```
AudiID   PriceMultiplier SeatRows
Audi01      1.0          8
Audi01      1.5          7
Audi01      2.0          6
Audi01      2.5          5
Audi01      3.0          4
Audi01      3.5          3
Audi01      4.0          2
Audi01      4.5          1
Audi01      5.0          0
Audi02      1.0          8
Audi02      1.5          7
Audi02      2.0          6
Audi02      2.5          5
Audi02      3.0          4
Audi02      3.5          3
Audi02      4.0          2
Audi02      4.5          1
Audi02      5.0          0
Audi03      1.0          8
Audi03      1.5          7
Audi03      2.0          6
Audi03      2.5          5
Audi03      3.0          4
Audi03      3.5          3
Audi03      4.0          2
Audi03      4.5          1
Audi03      5.0          0
```

Reserver

```
AudiID EventID SeatNumber
Audi01  1           7
Audi01  3           2
Audi01  4           4
Audi01  5           0
Audi01  6           1
Audi01  7           6
Audi01  8           3
Audi01  10          7
Audi01  2           0
Audi01  3           0
Audi01  5           1
Audi01  7           3
Audi01  1           4
Audi01  1           8
Audi01  1           4
Audi03  19          0
Audi03  20          1
Audi03  19          2
Audi03  20          3
```

I am not getting the correct total over here, and neither do I get other 2 events with total sales as 0. I am not sure what is wrong over here.

Comment: Please share complete/accurate table descriptions. The query refers to PriceMultiplier whereas the table lists SeatMultiplier. Are these columns the same? What do the columns mean?

Comment: @JosephB-Made the changes. Please check now.

Comment: Shouldn't the first join also include "and EventId=EventId" ?

Comment: @DariusX.- Yes agreed. However, there is still an issue with the query. Lot of events are not coming up, and the total also seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOINING on LEFT JOINS will give you unexpected results unless you know what you are doing. I've changed them all to left joins and added a few more fields into the group by statement to make the statement work. Not entirely sure if that will help you!?

This gives you Total Sales for each individual event (i.e. by date and start time).

```
SELECT AudiEvent.EventName, 
       AudiEvent.EventDate, 
       AudiEvent.StartTime, 
       SUM(Cast(AuditoriumRows.PriceMultiplier*AudiEvent.BasePrice as DECIMAL(4,1))) as "Total Sales" 

FROM AudiEvent 
LEFT JOIN Reserver ON AudiEvent.AuditoriumID=Reserver.AuditoriumID 
LEFT JOIN AuditoriumRows ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=AuditoriumRows.AuditoriumID 
LEFT JOIN Auditorium ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=Auditorium.AuditoriumID 
GROUP BY AudiEvent.EventName, AudiEvent.EventDate, AudiEvent.StartTime;
```

This gives you Total Sales for each individual event.

```
SELECT AudiEvent.EventName 
       SUM(Cast(AuditoriumRows.PriceMultiplier*AudiEvent.BasePrice as DECIMAL(4,1))) as "Total Sales" 

FROM AudiEvent 
LEFT JOIN Reserver ON AudiEvent.AuditoriumID=Reserver.AuditoriumID 
LEFT JOIN AuditoriumRows ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=AuditoriumRows.AuditoriumID 
LEFT JOIN Auditorium ON Reserver.AuditoriumID=Auditorium.AuditoriumID 
GROUP BY AudiEvent.EventName;
```

Comment: @Sarin- This does not seem to work. EventName is being duplicated with wrong Total Sales. Why are u grouping with all the 3 fields. Shouldn't grouping with EventName suffice over here?

Comment: @MrCoder The reason you are getting multiples is because you probably have more than one event with the same name on the same day i.e. starting at different times! This will give you the totals for events even if there are multiple on the same day starting at different times. I have added an additional example totalling all for the same event on the same day regardless of time.

Comment: just becasue mysql allows the person to group by on only one of teh stated fields ddoes not mean you should ever do that. It gives incorrect results when you do that. YOu should always use group by inteh standrd fashion of including all columns that are not aggreates in the group by for consitent results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  AudiEvent.EventName, 
        MAX(AudiEvent.EventDate), 
        MAX(AudiEvent.StartTime),
        COALESCE(SUM(Cast(AuditoriumRows.PriceMultiplier*AudiEvent.BasePrice as DECIMAL(4,1))), 0) as "Total Sales"
        from AudiEvent
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Reserver 
        ON AudiEvent.AuditoriumID=Reserver.AudiID
        AND Reserver.EventID = AudiEvent.EventID
        INNER JOIN AuditoriumRows 
        ON Reserver.AudiID=AuditoriumRows.AudiID
        AND Reserver.SeatNumber=AuditoriumRows.SeatRows
        INNER JOIN Auditorium 
        ON Auditorium.AuditoriumID = AudiEvent.AudiID
        GROUP BY AudiEvent.EventName;
```

I added extra join conditions (`Reserver.EventID = AudiEvent.EventID`) and (`Reserver.SeatNumber=AuditoriumRows.AudiID`).

Comment: We cannot make AuditoriumID equal to SeatRows over here. This will not work.

Comment: @MrCoder My bad, I meant to use the AudiID. Modifying the query.

Comment: Modified the query. Please check. When Reserver is joined with AuditoriumRows, the original query will fetch multiple rows for a single AudiID. Therefore, I added SeatRows in the join.